# highlight dates in arshaw fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using arshaw fullcalendar api for rendering calendar.
Now I know that TODAY is highlighted. Same I have a list of dates, that I want to highlight in week view. Also dates can be in different weeks.
Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you can render custom highlight with a little hack inside the viewDisplay callback :

```
viewDisplay : function( view ) { 

            startDate = view.start;

                var d = startDate.getDate();
                var m = startDate.getMonth();
                var y = startDate.getFullYear();

            cols = $('.fc-view-agendaWeek [class*="fc-col"].fc-widget-content')    

            for(i = 0 ; i<  cols.length ; i++){

                var colDate = new Date(y, m, d+i);


                if($.inArray(colDate.getTime() , hightligthedDays) > -1){

                    $(cols[i]).addClass("fc-state-highlight-other");

                   }
                else{

                    $(cols[i]).removeClass("fc-state-highlight-other");

                }
            }

            }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6kKS/3/)

Answer (score 2):

For agendaWeek and agendaDay view it can be possible by changing fullcalendar.js file.

Pass an additional paramter to fullcalendar say highlightDays

```
highlightDays: [0,3,4]   // List of days to highlight  0 - Sunday ... 6 - Saturday
```

In fullcalendar.js updateCells() method

```
if(opt('highlightDays').indexOf(date.getDay()) > -1)
{
    bodyCell.removeClass('ui-widget-content');
    bodyCell.addClass('fc-day-highlight');
}
```

Add colour you want to give to those days in  fc-day-highlight css class as

```
background-color: #dddddd;
```